# Google Apps script file upload, disable the submit button until a file is uploaded

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script

How can we disable the submit button on HTML UI service form till a file is uploaded on Google Drive . I don't want validation because i don't want to make the upload compulsory with the form data . A File loading message will do